# Build valid HTML from HTML Tags Using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contains HTML tag .
I just want to create a HTML FORM using this table is HTML FOrmat 
for eg.

```
ID Tags
-- ----
1  Html
2  Head
3  Title
4  Meta
5  Body
6  Font
```

Result should be

```
ID HTML                                 
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  <Html> <Head> <Title></Title> <Meta></Meta> </Head><Body> <Font></Font></Body</Html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, I really struggle to imagine a situation where there isn't a better way of achieving what you want. Why exactly do you need to get a form this way?

Comment: Where is a form involved? of those tags only FONT is valid within a form. Special case logic would be needed as some of those tags nest within others and there is no indication of that in the table data, are those 6 elements always present with the same ID? Your going to need to expand your question for a better answer

Comment: I work on a system that generates html from the database. Frankly the entire system is insane. Honestly - don't do it. How are you going to style the output for instance. Attributes?? Inner Text. My head hurts. If you must do this then generate the content as XML (like the answer below) then transform it with XSTL. I'm not even convinced that this is a good idea though.

Comment: It was a puzzle on a sql puzzle site..
I was curious about it so just posted it

Comment: Without additional information for closing tags the results will be ambiguous, e.g. if you have two `DIV` tags, does the first contain the second or is it implicitly closed by the second?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table(id int, tags varchar(50))
insert into @t values 
        (1, 'Html'),
        (2, 'Head'),
        (3, 'Title'),
        (4, 'Meta'),
        (5, 'Body'),
        (6, 'Font')

;with Tags1 as
(
    select xml1 = (select '<' + tags + '>' from @t for xml path (''))
)
,Tags2 as
(
    select xml2 = (select '</' + tags + '>' from @t order by id desc for xml path (''))
)
select replace(replace(Tags1.xml1 + Tags2.xml2,'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>')
from Tags1, Tags2
```